# Framer motion exit animation not working in PNPM mono repo

Tags: framer-motion, pnpm

I have a pnpm monorepo where I am bundling everything with vite and I am getting some strange behaviour with a framer motion component

```
<AnimatePresence>
    {open && (
        <Modal
            key="modal"
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{
                opacity: 0,
                transition: {
                    delay: 0.15,
                },
            }}
            transition={{
                type: 'spring',
                    duration: 0.5,
                }}
            >
         <Inner>
             <button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Close</button>
         </Inner>
      </Modal>
   )}
</AnimatePresence>
```

This animation fades in and out perfectly, however when I move it to an external package the animation works when entering but does not work on exit.